# Shift Register Nixie clock not displaying time

Tags: raspberry-pi, clock, shift-register

I am new to Python, mostly do hardware. I am attempting to create a Nixie clock base off of shift registers and a Raspberry PI 2. I found a similar project were the author included sample code, here http://www.smbaker.com/raspberry-pi-nixie-tube-clock-prototype

the hardware is set and function however there is something in a test code I found online that is preventing the Pi from displaying the time. The code as a test script that it would loop out of to display time. As I said I am new to Pi and Python I believe the obstacle I am having is at the end of the code. the digits display numbers 0.1.2.4.8 in a pattern sequence but never the time. I've included the code below.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import datetime

PIN_DATA = 23
PIN_LATCH = 24
PIN_CLK = 25
```

class Nixie:
    def **init**(self, pin_data, pin_latch, pin_clk, digits):
        self.pin_data = pin_data
        self.pin_latch = pin_latch
        self.pin_clk = pin_clk
        self.digits = digits

```
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

    # Setup the GPIO pins as outputs
    GPIO.setup(self.pin_data, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(self.pin_latch, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(self.pin_clk, GPIO.OUT)

    # Set the initial state of our GPIO pins to 0
    GPIO.output(self.pin_data, False)
    GPIO.output(self.pin_latch, False)
    GPIO.output(self.pin_clk, False)

def delay(self):
    # We'll use a 10ms delay for our clock
    time.sleep(0.010)

def transfer_latch(self):
    # Trigger the latch pin from 0->1. This causes the value that we've
    # been shifting into the register to be copied to the output.
    GPIO.output(self.pin_latch, True)
    self.delay()
    GPIO.output(self.pin_latch, False)
    self.delay()

def tick_clock(self):
    # Tick the clock pin. This will cause the register to shift its
    # internal value left one position and the copy the state of the DATA
    # pin into the lowest bit.
    GPIO.output(self.pin_clk, True)
    self.delay()
    GPIO.output(self.pin_clk, False)
    self.delay()

def shift_bit(self, value):
    # Shift one bit into the register.
    GPIO.output(self.pin_data, value)
    self.tick_clock()

def shift_digit(self, value):
    # Shift a 4-bit BCD-encoded value into the register, MSB-first.
    self.shift_bit(value&0x08)
    value = value << 1
    self.shift_bit(value&0x08)
    value = value << 1
    self.shift_bit(value&0x08)
    value = value << 1
    self.shift_bit(value&0x08)

def set_value(self, value):
    # Shift a decimal value into the register

    str = "%0*d" % (self.digits, value)

    for digit in str:
        self.shift_digit(int(digit))
        value = value * 10

    self.transfer_latch()
```

def main():
    try:
        nixie = Nixie(PIN_DATA, PIN_LATCH, PIN_CLK, 4)

```
    # Uncomment for a simple test pattern
    #nixie.set_value(1234)

    # Repeatedly get the current time of day and display it on the tubes.
    # (the time retrieved will be in UTC; you'll want to adjust for your
    # time zone)
    while True:
        dt = datetime.datetime.now()
        nixie.set_value(dt.hour*100 + dt.minute)

finally:
    # Cleanup GPIO on exit. Otherwise, you'll get a warning next time toy
    # configure the pins.
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

if **name** == "**main**":
    main()

Comment: can you please show us your effort?

Comment: Could you share the relevant code with us and tell us what the expected and actual outputs are? The way the question stands it's a bit hard to help out.

Comment: I added the code here is a you tube video   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BO5bVnpLL44

Comment: the code is supposed to allow me to display time on nixie tubes in a clock using 3 GPIO pins for Data, Latch and clock. using shift registers I can display multiple tubes. With the script running as is the tubes display 4x "0"'s. then run a sequence where it shifts through numbers. after the sequence the tubes return to 0 but never display the time.

Comment: the author wrote "# Uncomment for a simple test pattern
    #nixie.set_value(1234)" I deleted the "#" but the tubes did not display 1234.